# How to initialize a list of integer with certain gap in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to translate some of my Java algorithm codes into Python.

For the following Java code, I could not figure out a clean way to convert:

```
int[] groupBaseIndex = IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n < size, n -> n + step).toArray();
```

Basically, it generate an array from `0` to `size` with a `step`. For example, if `size=14` and `step=4`, it generates:

```
[0,4,8,12]
```

Can someone teach me how to convert this cleanly into Python? I am sure there must be a one liner to do this in Python.

Comment: Python has a range function for this. It makes an lazy iterator, but you can convert to a list : `list(range(0, 13, 4))` It takes, start, stop (not inclusive), step).

Comment: Or, if an immutable data structure works for you, then you can simply use `range(0, 13, 4)` and not convert the `range` object to a list, which has the added benefit of taking only a small, constant amount of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) method:

```
size = 14
step = 4
print(list(range(0, size, step)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 4, 8, 12]
```

Comment: or `size + 1` instead of `size`, so the 12 is included

Comment: @Dr.V It is included in the current code, no?

Comment: yes, sorry, even the java code has the `< size` condition.

Comment: depending on what they do next, it might be better to keep the range object

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to generate the list of values.

```
>>> groupBaseIndex  = [i for i in range(0, 13, 4)]
>>> groupBaseIndex
[0, 4, 8, 12]
>>>
```

alternative you can use `list(range())`, for example

```
>>> groupBaseIndex = list(range(0, 13, 4))
>>> groupBaseIndex
[0, 4, 8, 12]
>>>
```

Comment: actually, while it is worth mentioning comprehensions, the `range` call alone will do what the OP wants in this case.

Comment: `[x for x in whatever]` -> `list(whatever)`

Comment: @jsbueno no a range alone can't generate a list of values, you would need to pass the range into a list function for example `list(range(0, 13, 4))`

Comment: @Jared well, a `range` object is often a perfectly acceptable substitute for a list, i.e. whenever an immutable object would do. But more importantly, the list comprehension here is pointless and confusing because it isn't mapping/filtering anything, so it shouldn't be used

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated the answer to include both.

Comment: And as an extra additional content: you can now explain that `range` although not a "concrete repositry of numbers in memory" will most likely fulfill _any_ role for which the "materialized" list  would serve, but for string representation.